# TextToSpeech dont prononce the name of the first video

Tags: android, kotlin, text-to-speech

I have two activities:

- MainActivity
- PlayerActivity

The goal is to get the name of the videos selected by the user to be pronounced. The user can select a single video or several at once.

The video (s) are played using ExoPlayer but TextToSpeech does not speak the name of the first video, whether it is a selected video or the first of a selection. On the other hand, TextToSpeech speaks well the second video and the following ones.

Any advice will be welcome and appreciated, I spent the day yesterday and this morning looking without finding a solution.

```
private fun goToPlayer(theMvmt: String) {
    val intent = Intent(this@GokyoActivity, PlayerActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("mvmt", theMvmt)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

In PlayerActivity I initialize ExoPlayer and TextToSpeech:

Globale variable:

```
var tts: TextToSpeech? = null
```

In onCreate :

```
// Initialize TextToSpeech
tts = TextToSpeech(this, this)
```

Then out of onCreate

TextToSpeech:

```
   override fun onInit(status: Int) {
        val myLanguage = Locale.getDefault().displayLanguage
        if (androidAPILevel < 21) {
            val params: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap()
            params[TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_VOLUME] = musicVolume.toString() // change the 0.5 to any value from 0-1 (1 is default)
//            tts!!.speak("This is a volume test.", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, params)
        } else { // android API level is 21 or higher...
            val params = Bundle()
            params.putFloat(
                TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_VOLUME, musicVolume.toFloat()
            ) // change the 0.5f to any value from 0f-1f (1f is default)
//            tts!!.speak("This is a volume test.", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, params, null)
        }

        /* test de l'existence de la langue japonaise */
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            /* set the language for tts */
            val result = tts!!.setLanguage(Locale.FRENCH)
            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
//                tts!!.language = Locale.FRENCH
                Log.e("TTS", "*************** This Language is not supported ***************")
                speakOut(« French not supported, install it please")
                showTheToast(getString(R.string.NoJapaneseLanguage))
            } else {
                tts!!.setSpeechRate(1.0f)
            }
        } else {
            showTheToast("TextToSpeech initialization failed!")
        }
    }
```

ExoPlayer:

```
private fun initializePlayer() {
    player = SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this)
        .build()
        .also { exoPlayer ->
            viewBinding.videoView.player = exoPlayer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I answer to myself, I solve my problem.
I decided to use TextToSpeech also in my MainActivity for the first video and jump after that in the PlayerActivity for the rest.
It is certainly not the most elegant solution but it works.

Thanks for reading.